# How to join a comma after end of dict using python 3.4

Tags: python, dictionary, append, geojson, shapefile

Input: `a = {"item1": {"item2": "300"}}{{"item1": {"item2": "300"}}`

Output should be like: `{"item1": {"item2": "300"}}, {{"item1": {"item2": "300"}}`

Comment: This isn't valid Python code. Do you mean to assign `a` a tuple of two dictionaries? Or is this a string, such as `'{"item1": {"item2": "300"}}{{"item1": {"item2": "300"}}'`?

Comment: Thank you a lot for  reply .. I got output but how to remove single quote in json format like ['{......}']... so i need to remove single quote and square brackets ... please help me ...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is what you wanted to write?

```
a = {"item1": {"item2": "300"}}{{"item1": {"item2": "300"}}
```

Because, to create a dictionary, the curly brackets on that line aren't syntactically correct.

Unless you wanted `a` to be a string and want to insert a comma in that string?

Comment: see this code i am converting shapefile into geojson

Comment: output_buffer = []
    for features in range(0,layer.GetFeatureCount()):
        feat = layer.GetNextFeature()
        geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()
        result = feat.ExportToJson()

Comment: output_buffer.append(result)

Comment: Would adapting your code to something similar to this achieve the intended result? https://gist.github.com/frankrowe/6071443

Comment: output_buffer = []
    for features in range(0,layer.GetFeatureCount()):
        feat = layer.GetNextFeature()
        geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()
        result = feat.ExportToJson()
         output_buffer.append(result)
**when i am converting into geojson got output but only one features getting as json format like** 
**I got  output like :**
{"geometry": {"coordinates": [488081.726322771, 2360837.62927308], "type": "Point"}, "type": "Feature", "id": 0, "properties": {"EntityHand": null, "Layer": "pipe", "BB_D2", "ExtendedEn": n}}{"geometry": {...

Comment: output should get like:

Comment: "geometry": {"coordinates": [488081.726322771, 2360837.62927308], "type": "Point"}, "type": "Feature", "id": 0, "properties": {"EntityHand": null, "Layer": "pipe", "BB_D2", "ExtendedEn": n}},{"geometry": {... –

Comment: uploading files from the client side ...but i am getting out put .....EOF getting after only one feature id